# Suceeds on building but fails on running without debug

Tags: c++, runtime-error

## Q. Can someone point out the mistakes in this code?

Maybe there's a mistake in for cycle?

```
 for (; it != reg_end; ++it)
```

The code should read text and find number of words which have the same begin and end letter (for example, "runner", "streets", etc.). Text, which is used for data is in the same folder. The code suceeds on building but fails on running without debug, gives an error... Here's full code:

```
#include <fstream>  
#include <iostream>   // first error was here
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <regex>  
using namespace std;   
const string Cdfv = "Data.txt";
//------------------------------------------------------------
/** Class for counting words with the same begin 
  and end letters.
  Inherits string. */
class row: public string {
public:
    int equalBE(regex & re);
};
//------------------------------------------------------------
/** Finds and returns a number in a row of words, which begin 
  and end with the same letter. */
int row::equalBE(regex & re)
{
  int equalQuantity = 0;
  string word;
  sregex_token_iterator it(begin(), end(), re, -1);
  sregex_token_iterator reg_end;
  for (; it != reg_end; ++it) {
   word = it->str();           // second error was here, there was no ; mark 
   cout << word << endl;
   if (word[0] == word[word.length()-1])
      equalQuantity++;
  }
  return equalQuantity;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------
int AnalyseText(string dfv, regex & re);
//------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
  string punct = "[\\s,.;:-!?()]+";    // punctuation marks between words in a row
  regex re(punct);
  cout << "Number of words: " << AnalyseText(Cdfv, re) << endl;
  return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------
/** Counts and return number of words in a text,
  which begin and end with the same letter */
int AnalyseText(string dfv, regex & re)
{
  int equalQuantity = 0;
  ifstream fd(dfv.c_str());
  row rw;         
  while (!fd.eof()) {
    getline(fd, rw);
    equalQuantity += rw.equalBE(re);
  }
  fd.close();
  return equalQuantity;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------
```

Edit: this is the error that I get:

> ---
>
> ### Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>
> Debug Error!
>
> Program: ...klaidos pavyzdy\Zodziu_isskyrimas\Debug\Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe
>
> R6010
>
> - abort() has been called
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)
>
> ---
>
> ### Abort   Retry   Ignore

Edit: this is what I get in "Call Stack" window:

```
    KernelBase.dll!761ec42d()   Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]    
>   msvcr110d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 152    C++
    msvcp110d.dll!std::_Xregex_error(std::regex_constants::error_type _Code) Line 50    C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!std::_Parser<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,char,std::regex_traits<char> >::_Error(std::regex_constants::error_type _Code) Line 4757   C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!std::_Parser<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,char,std::regex_traits<char> >::_ClassRanges() Line 5093   C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!std::_Parser<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,char,std::regex_traits<char> >::_CharacterClass() Line 5117    C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!std::_Parser<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,char,std::regex_traits<char> >::_Alternative() Line 5420   C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!std::_Parser<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,char,std::regex_traits<char> >::_Disjunction() Line 5466   C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!std::_Parser<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,char,std::regex_traits<char> >::_Compile() Line 5498   C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!std::basic_regex<char,std::regex_traits<char> >::_Reset<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >(std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > _First, std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > _Last, std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type _Flags, std::forward_iterator_tag __formal) Line 2515 C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!std::basic_regex<char,std::regex_traits<char> >::basic_regex<char,std::regex_traits<char> ><std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & _Str, std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type _Flags) Line 2292   C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!main() Line 42    C++
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 536  C
    Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 377 C
    kernel32.dll!772a338a() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77eb9f72()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77eb9f45()    Unknown
```

Comment: @stuartd, I added it into description. :)

Comment: more like `reg_end` is uninitialized...

Comment: @FanųRinkimas So if you're running in Debug you can press "Retry" and then go to the "Call Stack" window. Start from the top and work your way down. Find the first file that you've edited and double click on it. You'll get dropped at the line that you're getting the failure on.

Comment: @JonathanMee, I added into description what I got in "Call Stack" window. Thanks

Comment: @FanųRinkimas Right so if you look through it I believe this line is your error: "Zodziu_isskyrimas.exe!main() Line 42    C++"

Answer (score 0):

your `it` doesn't start form anywhere if you look at the for loop. it should have a starting point e.g. `it = 0` or something.

```
  for (; it != reg_end; ++it) { // The prog. is failing dying for this
   word = it->str();           
   cout << word << endl;
   if (word[0] == word[word.length()-1])
      equalQuantity++;
  }
```

Also, if your `reg_end` is not initialise properly (just noticed due to someone's comment), it can result into "Undefined behaviour" which may cause issues. Seems like you are starting a for loop from "Somewhere" and running it until "Something is not satisfied" and increasing it every step.....

Answer (score 0):

It is because the string

```
"[\\s,.;:-!?()]+"
```

is not a valid regular expression in [ECMAScript syntax](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/). So the code:

```
    string punct = "[\\s,.;:-!?()]+";    // punctuation marks between words in a row
  regex re(punct);
```

throws a std::regex_error,  while no code catches it, so it crashes. It has nothing to do with debug or release version.

Type regex is  [basic_regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex/), by default, it use ECMAScript syntax to construct a regular expression. If you just remove "!?" in the string, it fix the error.